# JavaScript make a button that reveals text and images with one click?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button on my HTML page that reveals some images (and text) when a button is pressed. I want both to be revealed with one click and then hidden when the button is clicked again. I tried making a button that can be seen in my code that reveals an image but can't seem to figure out to have it reveal text as well.

```js
const showImage = () => {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<button onClick="showImage()">Button</button>
<div id="first" style="height:400px; width:400px; display:none;">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
</div>
```

Comment: Text can be inside a div just like an image can—what specific issue are you having?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, this should be what you are looking for.

```js
const showImage = () => {
   document.getElementById("first").classList.toggle('hidden');
 }
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="showImage()">Button</button>
 <div id="first" style="height:400px; width:400px;" class="hidden">
    <p>Som text</p>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
  </div>
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `.classList.toggle()`. This is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```js
let index=0 ; 
const showImage = () => {
  index++;
  if(index%2!=0){ 
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
      document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="showImage()">Button</button>
<div id="first" style="height:400px; width:400px; display:none;">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
  <div>.... The text you want to input .... </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a semantic HTML element called [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) that helps you to combine images with [captions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) which might be useful.

In this example I've

1. Removed your inline JS, cached the main elements in the JS, and used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a click listener to the button.
2. Used a CSS class (`.show`) that can be [toggled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) on/off (`flex`/`none`) using the element's [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). I've used [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) here to make aligning elements easier.

```js
// Cache the elements
const figure = document.querySelector('figure');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// When the button is clicked toggle 
// the show class on the figure
function handleClick() {
  figure.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
figure { display: none; margin-top: 1em; width: fit-content;}
img { border-radius: 5px; }
figcaption { margin-top: 0.25em; }
.show { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<button type="button">Show example</button>
<figure>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
  <figcaption>This is a lovely kitten.</figcaption>
</figure>
```